# definite Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

A integration is given,
$$M = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \left[\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{d\phi}{dx}\right)^2 + \frac{\lambda}{4}(\phi^2-v^2)^2\right] dx,$$  where $$m=v\sqrt\lambda$$ and $$ \phi(x)= v\tanh\left[ \frac{m}{\sqrt 2} (x-x_0)\right]$$

> How this integration gives =$\frac{2 \sqrt2}{3} \frac{m^3}{\lambda}?$

Comment: -1 for a poorly posed question. What is the variables over which you are integrating $x$ or $v$? What is $\phi$? Is there a relation between $v$ and $x$?

Comment: sorry ,
I'm fixing it now.

Comment: @user17762, hope you get the question now. :-)

Comment: $\phi$ looks like the kink solution in a $\phi^4$ theory. It seems you are missing a $\frac12$ factor in front of $\left(\frac{d\phi}{dx}\right)^2$.

Comment: Yup, right you are.  sorry , corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice

$$\frac{d\phi}{dx} = \frac{vm}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{\cosh(\frac{m}{\sqrt{2}}(x-x_0))^2}
= \frac{vm}{\sqrt{2}}\left(1 - \left(\frac{\phi}{v}\right)^2\right)
= \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2}}\left(v^2 - \phi^2\right)
$$

$M$ can be rewritten as:

$$M = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2}}+\frac{\lambda}{4}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lambda}}\right) (v^2 - \phi^2) \frac{d\phi}{dx} dx
= \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2}}\int_{-v}^{v} (v^2 - \phi^2) d\phi\\
= \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2}}\left(\frac43 v^3\right)
= \frac{2\sqrt{2\lambda}}{3}\left(\frac{m}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)^3 = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\frac{m^3}{\lambda}
$$

Comment: $$ \frac{vm}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{\cosh(\frac{m}{\sqrt{2}}(x-x_0))^2}
= \frac{vm}{\sqrt{2}}\left(1 - \left(\frac{\phi}{v}\right)^2\right)
$$
What is the basic law applied here?

Comment: @ComplexGuy It is just trigonometric identity: $$\frac{1}{(\cosh t)^2} = 1 - (\tanh t)^2$$

Comment: u guessed $\tanh t  = t$ here?

Comment: @ComplexGuy $t = \frac{m}{\sqrt{2}}(x - x_0)$ for this case.

Comment: Thnx, Got it completely, You done very elaborately.